# Retrieving value from Firebase displays old value, not the updated one

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display the score in the last storyboard. I mean after the game ends, but it does not display the updated value of the score. Instead, it displays the value of the previous game. In Firebase console the value is updated. I hope you understand my problem.

This is the code to compare the value in the current label and the value stored in the database, if the current value is bigger than the value in DB then overwrite it, not otherwise, then perform a segue and display the new big value stored in the DB.

```
 func getDatabaseScore(completion: @escaping (Int?)->()) {
            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child("user").child(userid)

            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
                    //Do not cast print it directly may be score is Int not string
                     completion(userDict["score"] as! Int?)

                    print(userDict["score"] as! Int?)

                }

                 completion(nil)
            })



    }

    func Counting() {
        counter -= 1
        timer.text = "\(counter)"
        if counter == 0 {
            timerCounter.invalidate()
            timerRunning = false
            self.getDatabaseScore() { score in
                // do something with "score"
                guard let score = score else { return }
                if score < self.scoreCounter{
                    print(self.scoreCounter)
                    ref.child("user").child((user?.uid)!).child("score").setValue(self.scoreCounter)
                }
            }

           print(self.scoreCounter)
            DispatchQueue.main.async{



                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "resultView", sender: self)


            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my code of the last segue to display the score in the label, the issue is it's not displaying the updated value of the current game which just ended:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child("user").child(username).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
         if let userDict2 = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {

             print(userDict2["score"])
            self.resultLabel.text = "\(userDict2["score"] as! Int?)"
        }

    })


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: Does user.uid and username the same thing? Because if not you are observing the wrong node.

Comment: Did this got fixed